# Confirmation on Proof of $(ST)^2=0$ where $\operatorname{range}S\subset\operatorname{null} T$

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

Is the Following Proof Correct? I know the Problem is fairly simplistic but i get the feeling that perhaps i am missing something.

**Theorem.** Given that $V$ is a vector space  and $S,T\in\mathcal{L}(V,V)$ such that 
$$\operatorname{range}S\subset\operatorname{null}T\tag{1}$$ then $(ST)^2=0$

**Proof.** Let $v$ be an arbitrary vector in $V$ and assume that $Tv = w$ consequently 
$$(ST)^2(v) = (S(T(S(Tv)))) = S(T(Sw))$$
but $(1)$ implies that $T(Sw)=0$ consequently
$$S(T(Sw))=S(0)=0$$

$\blacksquare$

Comment: Yeah, the key is $TS=0$ so $(ST)^2=S(TS)T=0$. It's worth being explicit why $TS=0$.

Comment: $T\circ S=0$, and you have proved that in between.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proof is correct, but there is a passage that could be improved, in my opinion. That's when you write “assume that $Tv=w$”. This is the first time that the vector $w$ is mentioned, but your expression suggests that the reader should know it already. I would have written “let $w=Tv$”.